# What is the best way to wait for validity check within onSubmit

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a reactive form which has async validators to a server API. Because of special circimstances I need to  revalidate the Form within the submit function. I currently struggle with how to wait the revalidation to be finished. Please advice. Thanks you.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();

  someObservable() // what to put here?
  .subscribe((stillValid: boolean) => {
    if (stillValid) send();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I wrote about the lack of ability to handle this elegantly with Angular forms.
[Success Handling is Everyone's Responsibility](https://medium.com/@BenRacicot/success-handling-is-everyones-responsibility-40d844e6cc42)

> If we could write custom events into FormGroup’s statusMessages the
>   possibilities are endless. But we can’t.

There is no way to know or use any type of success event. One exists but it not usable from a reactive forms perspective. [The Angular team knows about this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28743).

Here's what I do when I have several forms on a page:

```
public onSubmit(subject: string, index: number) {
    if (!this.form.valid) { return; } // validity check
    this.formSuccess(index);
}

public formSuccess(index): void {
    this.success[index] = false;
    if (this.success[index] === false) {
        this.success[index] = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.success[index] = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

View: `.submitted.success` fades in for 5 seconds and fades back out.

```
<div class="submitted" [ngClass]="{'success': success}">
    Thanks for submitting!
</div>
```

(I'll work on making a simplistic StackBlitz example and post back)

Answer (score -1):

Subscribe to statusChanges,

```
this.myForm.statusChanges.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(status => {
  if (status === 'VALID') send();
})
```

Comment: I had the same thought. However, I can still see, that VALID appears before the asyn validator is running

Comment: skip the first value